# Recover password while logged in on iPhone

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I am in a quite a chicken and egg situation with my Gmail account:

- I forgot my password so I can't access from desktop.
- I am logged in on my iPhone Gmail app.
- The phone number is not related to the account so can not be used as a recovery method.

I think Google is detecting I am logged in the phone so any attempt to recover the password is not working. I can automatically log in with Safari in the phone, but from there, if I want to change the password it will ask me for the previous one.

Can I use the logged in phone access in any good way to change my Gmail password?

Comment: this is not possible, the password on the phone is encrypted, imagine that it will be horrible if you had stolen a phone and are able to recover it. You can see Google always prompt you a page to enter an phone number and/or alternative email address for recovery purpose.

Comment: do you remember app password?

Comment: If you are logged into your Google account within Safari that means you can update the phone number associated with the account.  If this turns out not to be possible, you are out of luck, a password change requires the previous password while doing a password reset does not but required VALID recovery information which you don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update] Finally found impossible to use the fact of being logged in the App so I had to go through the painful recovery process that took dozens of tests filling information till I recovered the password.

Answer (score -1):

Go to [this](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/?hl=si&ard=AHwGkRmcchW5XCkh5f-9HSFSeLXhazsB_LVFWTDUfH9GB0Xqv4dkrKH-VGQNnjqGCKe1pIII7emYEBZWISB1d8JMz8z98vyu3Nsd0GOtifnzzEhy1g34l4m9duUJua5heQ4grQDdgvIgq7oHcOWHzVwaQklmTKNRBQ) link and follow Google instructions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: so do I have to put all my password recovery screen shots here? this link was google official one..so if they change it, it will automatically redirect to the new one.
If someone knows how to put a question here, he/she should know how to follow these steps.

Comment: Summarize the information.  I or anyone who reads your answer shouldn't have to click a link, to understand, what they need to do to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok. you better to do it instead of posting the same comment everywhere.

Comment: The comment is automatically generated by the review queue.  The purpose of the comment is to get YOU to summarize the information, if I wanted to do it, I would just post an answer myself.  I will reverse my vote, once the question, is more then just a link to a google support article.  I am really starting to get upset at comments like this, I am basically taking your comment as, you are taking offense to a comment that is automatically generated when I click on a button within the review queue.  If I wanted that heartache i would just write my own comments.

Comment: This link does not add any useful information. I wanted to know if there is a way I can use the fact I am already logged in the phone.

Comment: Yes, follow the instruction given in google. first I forgot my password etc.